# html2canvas Limitations size/data/width/height

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2canvas

I am trying to build a canvas, specifically a family tree, that is very wide and may have many images. If I build the tree without images, the width can span out to 27,000 px and the file size hits 1.7mb. If I build the tree with images for every node the width can span out to 16,385px and the file size hits 2.7mb. I am creating a custom window size based on the canvas element to override the browsers limitations, as specified here: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/faq . I have also set the scale to 1 (the default).

The issue is if I go over these widths some of the nodes may render blank on Chrome and Firefox, and on IE the canvas gets cut off.

The question comes down to is there some sort of limitation to the amount of data html2canvas can write? Is there a limitation to the width even after the browser limitations are overwritten?

Specifications:
html2canvas version tested with: html2canvas 1.0.0-alpha.12
Browser & version: Chrome Version 78.0.3904.70 (Official Build) (64-bit) , IE-11 Version: 11.805.17763.0, Firefox Quantum: Version 70.0.1 (64-bit)
Operating system: Windows 10

Comment: "even after the browser limitations are overwritten" what does that mean? The limitations listed there can not be overwritten, you must fit in. Now, for your more general problem, do you really have to produce the image on front-end? Sounds like you could probably make an svg of it and use a server-side program (e.g batik) to generate a bitmap version of it if you really need one. You'd only face png's limitations then.

Comment: Hi @Kaiido, the issue is not building the tree on the UI, it breaks when I save the document as an image. Doing that with html2canvas if you do not specify the window size then html2canvas defaults to the browsers limitations and if the window devicePixelRatio is greater than 1 then the image will multiply in pixels. So according to their docs you can create a custom window size based on the canvas element and set the pixelRatio to 1. This is a small edge case and was wondering if anyone has ran into similar issues saving a really large HTML doc. Maybe html2canvas has memory limitations..

Comment: I do understand the issue, and once again, it's not something you can overwrite, it's just an hard limit browsers have set and you must fir in their limits. You didn't answer any of my questions. html2canvas doesn't manage any memory, the limitations will come from the device where the code is being ran, but once again, are you sure you need to do it on front-end?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am really just maintaining this section of code for a company vs building from scratch and currently they have it designed to work on the front end, but I will look into your recommendation of making an svg and use a server side program to generate a bitmap.